# Delete all Duplicate mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate lines with the same badge_id and we check the user_id :

For example, with the following data:

```
id  user_id   badge_id   badge_slot
1   2         ACH_1           0
2   1         ACH_1           0
3   1         ACH_1           0
4   1         AAAAA           0
```

How to delete ??

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the records with the lowest `id` you can use `min()`

```
delete from your_table
where id not in
(
   select * from 
   (
     select min(id)
     from your_table
     group by user_id, badge_id
   ) x
)
```

And in MySQL you have the problem that you can't select from the same table that you are deleting from. But you can overcome this by a subselect.

Comment: I used it in my answer: `select * from (place subselect here) alias_name`

Comment: I tried but it does not work with Several lines my table has 1801490 lines how should I do?

Comment: I tested with some 20 line it works well but the query not work with 1801490 lines ??

Comment: I tested with some 20 line it works well but the query not work with 1801490 lines ??

Comment: Again, what does not working mean? Don't duplicates get deleted? Does it run forever? Does the computer explode?

Comment: Having almost 2 mio records makes it run long. If you only need to run this once then wait it out. You can add a `limit 1000` for instance at the end of the query to see how long it takes to delete 1000 records. If you run this query more often then you should add some indexes to your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      DELETE * ,count(*)as n your_table by badge_id HAVING n>1 .
```

hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
      ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1('badge_id','user_id');
```